# How to Make a <td> Clickable As a Link (Without Javascript)

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I am writing some code for sending HTML e-mails. Due to the non-standard nature of e-mail clients, I am restricted to some pretty antediluvian code (no Javascript, no divs, no CSS shortcuts, etc.)

The call-to-action buttons are TDs but so far I haven't been able to make the whole button clickable; just the text in the middle.

The code is something like

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" width="33%" style="background-color:#6483c1; border:1px solid #44619a; border-radius:2px; padding-top:20px; padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:10px;">
            <a href="http://littlehotels.co.uk/travelinsurance.php" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;"><font size="3" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#ffffff"><b>Travel Insurance</b></font></a>
            </td>
```

I have already tried adding `display:block` to the td style, but that didn't work.

Am I trying to do the impossible?

Comment: Have you tried styling the `<a>` tag and making the `td` invisible-ish? I think that'll ultimately work better

Comment: until a CSS nut answers, try setting your `<a style="line-height: 42px">`, or some variation of `auto` or `100%`. Setting the `line-height` a common answer for "I need my <span>'s clickable effects to also work above & below its text." Prepare for your `<a>` to vertically center, though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the anchor a block level element and move the padding from the table cell to the anchor:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="33%" style="background-color:#6483c1; border:1px solid #44619a; border-radius:2px;">
      <a href="http://littlehotels.co.uk/travelinsurance.php" target="_blank" style="padding:20px 10px;display:block;color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;"><font size="3" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#ffffff"><b>Travel Insurance</b></font></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I love it when the solution is so elegantly simple. It looks like everyone was steering me in the same directions, but this answer gets the green tick for it's clarity of explanation. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a `<td>` clickable without JS
Enlarge the inner `<a>` size instead - to cover the needed area,
setting it's `display` to `block` might help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, it is not precisely what you are asking for, but should give you want you want - even in Outlook! You were on the right track, but the CSS stylings should be on the a tag instead. The best part is that there is a free online tool that can create the code for you.

Go to [buttons.cm](http://buttons.cm/) and it will create the html and VML needed to give you a fully clickable button in HTML/CSS and not just as an image.

Added code output from buttons.cm as reference in case it ever gets taken down:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" width="33%"><div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://littlehotels.co.uk/travelinsurance.php" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#44619a" fillcolor="#6483c1">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Travel Insurance</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://littlehotels.co.uk/travelinsurance.php"
style="background-color:#6483c1;border:1px solid #44619a;border-radius:2px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Travel Insurance</a></div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```